# Wordpress theme, sidebar location

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I bought a non-wordpress theme that I'm currently adapting to wordpress. The only problem I have is the location of the sidebar. It loads in the same area as the main content for some reason.

End of header file:

```
    <!--Content Sec -->
        <div id="content_sec1">
            <!--Main Section-->
            <div class="col1">
```

And the start of the footer file:

```
 </div> <!--col1 end -->
<div class="col2">
                <?php
                    /* 
                     *  Load the sidebar
                     */
                    get_sidebar();
                ?>
</div>
```

As said the sidebar loads in the end of the col1 div instead of in the col2 div as it should. The col2 div remains empty.

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Can you show us the code between these two snippets?

Comment: theres no code between these snippets, besides the code generated by wordpress.

Comment: I suppose so, but the idea behind my request is that some div may get messed up somewhere between header and footer - have you checked that? `get_sidebar()` doesn't do anything that can lead to this behaviour. As far as I'm aware, it just prints the sidebar, nothing that may rearrange the code.

Comment: I doubt it, seems like the get_sidebar() doesn't actually do anything. If i remove it the same thing happen. If I on the other hand put something else, like text etc, in the same place as the get_sidebar(), it's placed as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what we've discussed, I assume that there is a call to get_sidebar() somewhere between header and footer - take a look at single.php, page.php, etc. Or just run a grep in the theme directory and see where it is: `grep -rn 'get_sidebar' .`

Comment: Ah yeah, there's the problem! Thanks alot :)